# How do I put an element above any given element in the DOM with simple JavaScript/CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

I want to use JavaScript to put a new element (very like a notification bubble) on the top-right corner of any element of the page. What is the simplest way?

And I need these conditions:

1. The target element can be any element on this page, for instance, in a div that can scroll internally.
2. The new element should go with the target one, even if the user resize or scroll the page.

I guess is to calculate the size of that target and then add some element with some styles like `top` or `right`, but I don't know how to really achieve it.

Thanks for any kind of tips.

Comment: so you just want to append an element that's top right aligned to another element? Is this on a specific event and does the new element need to be removed at some point?

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS for this.
Parent div will be position relative:

```
.someDiv{position: relative}
```

Then put the notification div above the parent div like this:

```
    <div class="someDiv">
      <span class="notiBubble">{{DYNAMIC DATA}}</span>
    </div>
```

css:

```
 .notiBubble{
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    right: -10px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #ff0;
    padding: 9px 15px;
    z-index: 999;
    border-radius: 100%;
 }
```